# How to tell list from non-list in Django template?

Tags: python, django

I've got a Django template I'd sometimes like to pass a list and sometimes like to pass a single value.  How can the template tell which it was given?

I'm thinking the value would be set like one of these:

```
context = {
    'foo' : 'bar
}
```

or:

```
context = {
     'foo' : ['bar', 'bat', 'baz']
}
```

Then, the template would have code that looks something like this:

```
{% if foo isa list %}
    {% for item in foo %}
        {{ item }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ item}}<br>
{% endif %}
```

I can set it up to have foo or foolist, for example, and check for one or the other.  However, it'd be a bit nicer (imo) to just have foo that was either a list or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to do it this way then just add a check that it doesn't have `format`(in case of string) method and has `0` index, if so then its a list else considered single value

```
{% if foo.0 and not foo.format %}
    {% for item in foo %}
        {{ item }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ item}}<br>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: But if `foo` is a string, wouldn't `foo.0` just return a first character?

Comment: That looks excellent -- nice and simple to code, easy for folks to understand, and should fit well with the existing code.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this will work. The Django template language will call the `reverse()` method. This will return `None`, so the if tag will evaluate to `False`. Since `reverse()` acts in place, the list will be reversed, which you probably don't want.

Comment: @Alasdair: Really good catch there. (y). Updated answer and tested as well to make sure.

Comment: I was just about to check in and say the previous version didn't seem to work when I found this fix.  I put it in place and all is well.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is needlessly complicated.
I would just go with a list:

**views.py**

```
foo_list = ['bar']
context = {
    'foo': foo_list,
    'foo_len': len(foo_list),
}
```

**template**

```
{% if foo_len == 1 %}
    {{ foo.0 }}
{% else %}
    {% for item in foo %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This might be needlessly complicated, but it's to be used in legacy code.  The method I describe is (probably) the simplest way to keep code, coders, and schedule happy.  Thanks for the suggestion.